# PHP If array value is present then echo text

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP Script, and a HTML form that will send POST values to the php page. My problem is, when I select the "override schedule message" and submit the form, it displays the correct message, However when I go directly to the url.php, it displays the same message every time, regardless of what was submitted on the form.

The indented behavior is when the form is submitted and the "override schedule message" is selected, the url.php will display "*Override is on, and would display rss feed*"

If "display message for schedule" is selected, then "*overide is not on, and would display time based message
Array ( [0] => )*" should display.

**Php Code:**

```
        <?php
    
    if ($_POST['override'] == 'value2' ) {
            $myArray=array("");
            array_push($myArray,"override");
            }
            else{
                $myArray=array("");
            }
    ?>
    <?php
    
     if (in_array("override", $myArray)) {
        echo "Override is on, and would display rss feed";
        echo "<br>";
        print_r($myArray);
     }
     else{
             echo "overide is not on, and would display time based message";
        echo "<br>";
        print_r($myArray);
     }
        
    ?>
```

**HTML Form**

```
<form style="margin: auto; width: 95%; padding:10px;" action="https://example.com/url.php" method="post" >
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="override" value="value1">
    <label class="radio-label">Display message for schedule</label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="override" value="value2">
    <label class="radio-label">Override schedule message</label>
  </div>
<input class="ppw_submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: What should appear if I select "Display message for schedule" ?

Comment: overide is not on, and would display time based message
Array ( [0] => )

Comment: I deleted my previous answer since I probably misunderstood. If I open the PHP without any form being submitted I currently see `overide is not on, and would display time based message
Array ( [0] => )` what would you like to see instead?

Comment: The intended behavior would be to see the correct message, based off the form submission, on submit AND when accessing the page directly.

Comment: The use of this is to override the time based message on the url.php page when you submit the override form. Therefore the correct message must display when it is submitted and when you access the page directly. My code in the OP displays the intended behavior only when submitted but not when accessing the url directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how HTTP protocol works. The protocol is stateless, which means - if two requests have the same content, the server should return the same response. Let's look at your requests.

When you submit the form, you are sending a `POST` HTTP request to the server. The request parameters are taken from the submitted form.

Similarly, when you go directly to the URL, you are sending a `GET` HTTP request with no parameters. The stateless nature of the HTTP doesn't allow the server to "remember" the submitted form, because it was submitted in another request.

If you want the server to remember the form being sent, you have basically two options. One of them is to use cookies, which means that the server tells the client to remember something and send it to the server with all following requests. The cookies are basically an implementation of states to the stateless protocol.

The second option is to implement some kind of persistence on the server. This usually means a database or file storage, depending on what you are trying to achieve.

The server will not remember what was in the `$myArray` variable during the previous request but if you save it to disk or DB, you can retrieve the previous value during the next request.

Comment: I believe this is my exact issue. I wasn't aware that the array value wouldn't be remembered on the server, and hence was not being displayed if I accessed the page directly. I will try modifying the code to use a mySQL database instead.

Comment: If this answer was what you needed, please consider marking it as accepted. It would give me a few reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, I couldn't understand why it doesn't do what you intended. I copied it onto a LAMP box and it worked exactly the way you intended. Either you've copied and pasted the wrong file or your opcode cache is configured to not check file timestamps.

Maybe I misunderstood what you were trying to day.

> However when I go directly to the url.php, it displays the same message every time

I presume you mean access the page without going via the form? Which same message? `$_POST['override']` will not be "value2" so if you are not POSTing override=value2 then the page will always output "overide is not on, and would display time based message".

Values in $_POST and $_GET only last as long as it takes for the php to execute and generate the page.